# IsNullOrWhiteSpace check for Java

Tags: java, strings, null

I am needing to write my own `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check for Java but am wondering if this is the best method to do so

```
public static boolean isStringNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    if (isStringNullOrEmpty(value)){
        return true;
    }

    for (Character chars : value.toCharArray()){
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(chars)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the class called, and what other methods are in it?

Comment: @200_success it is called StringUtils. Basically, it is trying to simulate .NET string utilities.

Comment: An emptystring is neither whitespace nor null.. your method still returns true for it. Either that shouldn't be the case or your method isn't named correctly

Comment: @Vogel612 This is how .NET behaves. Like I said, I am trying to simulate .NET behaviour.

Comment: The .NET source code for the [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55e241b6143365ef) method is available online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have to check a profiler, but otherwise just iterating over the
string would be best, since you then don't have any allocations going
on, i.e.:

```
public static boolean isStringNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(value.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1. Besides not allocating, this is the most direct translation of the .NET implementation that Alexander linked to.

Answer (score 17):

I agree that the String should be left out of the name, as this is quite obvious in StringUtils. How about this short version?

```
public static boolean isNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    return value == null || value.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this is basically [how it is done in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) although they check the length of the trimmed string rather than using `isEmtpy()` like this `return value == null || value.trim().length == 0;` although they claim that it has better performance than just writing that code would.

Comment: **Note:** this is equivalent to the [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#23a8597f842071f4) method in .NET, whereas [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#55e241b6143365ef) is the appropriate method to use when also checking for strings with only white space characters. The OP's proposed solution is practically identical to the .NET method *(aside from  the additional method call in the stack)*.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your note's point, @Alexander. C#'s String.IsNullOrEmpty returns true if the given string is null or empty string, but false for "\t \r\n". C#'s String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, and the answer above, will return true for null, empty string, and "\t \r\n". This answer is equivalent to (and more readable than) C#'s String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, which is what the OP is trying to replicate.

Comment: This method will produce different results in some nontrivial cases. `isWhitespace` and `trim` have different notion on what is a whitespace character. For example `NULL` (`"\0"`) is trimmed but `isWhitespace` returns false. `IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` (`"\u3000"`) is another example.

Answer (score 6):

Having "String" in the method name is doubly redundant: first, because it is in a class called `StringUtils`, and also because the compiler will handle any overloading based on the parameter type. .NET does likewise and calls it [`IsNullOrWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You could generalize it for the [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface.

```
public static boolean isNullOrWhitespace(CharSequence value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(value.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or if you're using Java 8:

```
public static boolean isNullOrWhitespace(CharSequence value) {
    return value == null || value.codePoints().allMatch(c -> Character.isWhitespace(c));
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the nice Java 8 solution. Doesn't actually fit the requirements of emulating the .NET behaviour, but, as an implementation that one would expect from the method's name, it is very good.

Comment: @Nihathrael hm, how does it behave differently?

Comment: I think for an empty string yours will return false, I might be missing something?

Comment: @Nihathrael From [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-): `true if either all elements of the stream match the provided predicate or the stream is empty, otherwise false`. Exactly like C#'s [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You should be consistent with your coding style. If you use braces `{}` for single `if` statements you should use them each time.

You should replace the check `isStringNullOrEmpty(value)` with `(value==null)`

```
public static boolean isStringNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    if (value == null){
        return true;
    }

    for (Character chars : value.toCharArray()){
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(chars)){
             return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

as `value.toCharArray()` just returns an empty array if `value.length() == 0`.

For the naming I go with @200_success. You should call it `isNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your way of doing the check is fine!

It should be favored over the code snipped in the accepted answer of Nihathrael.
That solution is significantly less performant and would be marked as shortcoming by code quality inspection tools. The invocation of `trim()` may implicate the creation of a new string object.

See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819800/whats-the-better-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-empty-than-using-string-trim-len
- http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.5/rules/strings.html#InefficientEmptyStringCheck

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using regular expressions? "Best" is always relative in the context of code, but if I were doing it, I might do something like this:

```
public static boolean isStringNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w*$");    //pattern for 0 or more whitespace characters
    if (value == null || pattern.matcher(value).find()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This basically uses a regular expression for zero or more whitespace characters in a string, and checks your value against it; then returns the result. It's built into java.util.regex. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The "empty" part can be also checked by using regex — if the entire string is matched by `\s*`, then it's empty or whitespace.